# jQuery UI shake effect starts on new line

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, shake

On the jsfiddle link provided below, I have a paragraph with text, and then an input box. I use jQuery UI to shake the input box, but bizarrely the shake effect starts one line below the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/VQj2Z/6/

Comment: There is no such tag as `</input>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you check source code during the effect, you see that the input is wrapped by `<div class="ui-effects-wrapper">` and this is why it folds to next line. I am not familiar with mootools, but quick'n'dirty fix would be to assign `display:inline` to that div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-effects-wrapper {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Why would you need to be familiar with Mootools?

Comment: Because thats what "framework" bar said in original link. Anyway, your suggestion of floating divs makes more sense  (y).

Comment: I would like to do this without a hack. Thanks, though.

Comment: @ThA-B:  Oh, I see... Mootools is just the JSFiddle default even though it's not being used.  He manually included jQuery and jQuery UI in the HTML section.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's not enough room (it's dynamically wrapped in a div) for the `input` to shake while "inline", it wraps to the next line and just goes back when it's done.

Put the text and the `input` into block level elements (floating side-by-side `div`'s) and everything stays in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/VQj2Z/10/

Also note that I removed `</input>` as there's no such thing.  `<input` is simply closed with a `/>`

Comment: This involves changing my previous work too much, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Randomblue:  The problem is simple... jQuery UI dynamically encloses the object in a `div` before it shakes it.  The `div` won't fit "inline" and will always wrap.  I can't see your previous work but I don't know how else you're going to fix this without changing something integral.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I just added these attributes to the class of the containing div:

```
overflow:    visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

I figured the situation causing the whitespace wrapping was probably only a few pixels, so why not let the horizontal overflow slightly go over and then force it not to wrap? For my use case, this seemed to be the minimally invasive approach since the text was supposed to be on only one line anyway.